# Trying to make pancakes

Tags: javascript

I’m working on a fun task I found while search through to make robust validation, below is only my code for validation.

```
Pan = “1234567890-=[]{}%^*+_\|~<>€$¥•.,?!/()£&@“ # this is my list that I’m going to check an input against

Valid = False
while Valid ==False:
         Valid = True
         Forename=input(“Please enter name”)
         For i in range (0,len(pan)):
                if input[i] in pan == False:
                    Valid == False
```

I get a syntax error in the line

```
if input[i] in pan == False:
```

The message is

> TypeError: ‘builtin_function_or_method’ object is not subscriptable

Sorry in advance for being a bit of noo

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your posted code.  For one thing, you require that the input name be made of characters in **Pan** -- names are usually alphabetic, so I'm worried that your logic is reversed.  However ...

1. This code does not produce the given output: the misspelled "for" will draw an earlier error.
2. You need to index the variable holding your input, not the input function.  That's the error you got.
3. Learn to think in Boolean terms: any time you have "== False" or "== True", you're not doing this properly.
4. Grab the input only once -- don't make the user enter it for every character check.

Here's your code after these updates:

```
pan = “1234567890-=[]{}%^*+_\|~<>€$¥•.,?!/()£&@“  # valid characters

forename = input(“Please enter name”)

valid = False
while not valid:
     valid = True       # input is good until we get a bad value
     for i in range (0, len(forename)):
         if forename[i] not in pan:
             valid = False
             break
```

Next, note that you never actually need the index of each character; you need only the characters.  user6731765's answer shows this update.

For advanced shortening, learn the *all* and *any* functions; *all* works here to check the entire input string easily:

```
 forename = "INVALID NAME"

 # Are all the name's characters found in pan?
 while not all(char in pan for char in forename):
     forename = input(“Please enter name”)
```

Comment: Right thanks I’m still fairly new to computing but thanks for helping me out here

Comment: Glad to be of help.  We've all been new at some point.  That's why I gave you a solution using your current set of tools, and then another with some advanced tools.

Comment: You absolute legend though, nothing better than seeing your code work

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

- Checking if `input[i]` it not in `Pan` should be done by using `not`
- `Valid==False` should be `Valid=False` because you're setting a variable
- `For` should start with a lowercase

Try using the following, I cleaned up the variables a little

```
pan = “1234567890-=[]{}%^*+_\|~<>€$¥•.,?!/()£&@“ # this is my list that I’m going to check an input against

valid = False
while valid == False:
     valid = True
     forename = input("Please enter name")
     for i in range (0,len(pan)):
         if input[i] not in pan:
             valid = False
```

Here's a more concise version

```
name = input("Please enter a name")
valid = True
for char in pan:
    if char in name:
        valid = False
        break
```

Comment: Thanks man, but I don’t understand what char is, pls could you explain

Comment: Char is merely a variable that stands for a single character.  Note that this works equally well if you swap **pan** and **name** in the middle two lines.